# Sanitise low search keywords

Tags: search, low-search, strip-html

What's a good method for stripping HTML from our site search? I've found that it's possible to inject HTML directly into our page like this:

```
https://website.co.uk?keywords="<svg/onload%3Dconfirm(//)>
```

The page source then looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/sanitise-low-search-keywords?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=19898976#reply_19898976) and got a fix. We were using `{get:keywords}` when we should have been using `{low_search_keywords}`. That tag sanitises HTML for you. Hope that helps someone...